# JS variable returning object not value

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, global

I'm setting a global variable via jQuery as such:

```
user = $("#user").val();
```

Specifically without `var` so that it can be pulled outside of `function`.

When I try to pull that variable later all I get is `[object HTMLInputElement]`.

Here is the code I'm using to pull that variable,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById("user-login-info").innerHTML = "Hello, "+user;
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "Specifically without `var` so that it can be pulled outside of function". DO NOT DO THIS

Comment: can you share your javascript ?
What are you trying to achieve ?
Did you use a window.onload event ?
Did you use an onclick or something to show the value ?

Comment: share your whole code at www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: I'll post a fiddle but here is what I'm trying to do.
I'm using an ajax call to a php file that will tell me if a username/password is authenticated, and if it IS correct, I want to save that username to be used to say hello on the next jQuery mobile page (same html file). Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/redphyre/5efcvfqg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked it and modified a little

```
$("#login-submit").click(function() {
                    user = $("#user").val();
                    pass = $("#pass").val();
                    var dataString = "user="+user+"&pass="+pass;
                    var linkString = "index.html#home";
                    if (user == "" || pass == "") {
                        alert("Please fill in all fields");
                    }
                    else {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "http://www.weddingindustryinsider.com/VAWEAPP/login.php",
                            data: {user: user, pass: pass},
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(result) {
                                if (result = "1") {
                                    alert("Login Sucess.");
                                    setTimeout(location.href = linkString,1000);
                                }
                                else { alert("Username or Password incorrect. Please try again."); }
                            },
                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                });
```